# Unable to get graph api user groups using access token using MSALjs

Tags: asp.net, azure, angular8, azure-ad-msal

I am using msaljs in angular with .net. I am able to get a v2 oauth token but in .net, the GetMyMemberOfGroupsAsyncmethod returns a 401 with invalid compact token error. I tried changing the scopes in the application but to no use.

Here's the angular config file

```
{
"msalConfig": {
    "clientId": "CLIENT_ID",
     "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/",
     "validateAuthority": true,
     "redirectUri": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "postLogoutRedirectUri": "http://localhost:3000/"
  },
  "angular": {
    "popUp": false,
    "consentScopes": [
      "user.read.all",
      "directory.Read.all"
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the token parsed via JWT.io

```
{
  "aud": "AUD",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/v2.0",
  "iat": 1592242137,
  "nbf": 1592242137,
  "exp": 1592246037,
  "aio": "",
  "email": "",
  "family_name": "",
  "given_name": "",
  "name": "",
  "nonce": "",
  "oid": "",
  "preferred_username": "USERNAME",
  "sub": "",
  "tid": "",
  "uti": "",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

The exception occurs in the last line of the below code segment:

```
        public async Task<List<Group>> GetMyMemberOfGroupsAsync(string accessToken)
        {
            List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
            PrepareAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);
            // Get groups the current user is a direct member of.
            IUserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage memberOfGroups = await graphServiceClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
```

I get the following exception on my .net backend

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   Status Code: Unauthorized
>   Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
>   Message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217
>   Inner error:
>           AdditionalData:
>           date: 2020-06-16T12:44:50
>           request-id: ce0a83bf-3e33-4510-b4f6-9840dfb85a8a
>   ClientRequestId: ce0a83bf-3e33-4510-b4f6-9840dfb85a8a

The endpoints use v2.0. Also, i tried adding protected resource maps like the following in the config file but the token seems to be unaffected:

```
    protectedResourceMap: [
        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
    ];
```

Comment: That looks like an ID token, but what you need is an access token for MS Graph API.. I'm not too familiar with MSAL in Angular :\

Comment: how do you prepare your graphServiceClient?

Comment: Please check your permission for [GET-/me/memberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) i.e., add Directory.Read.All in your permission and let us know if it helps you.

Comment: Adding Directory.Read.All didn't help unfortunately. The problem is that no matter what I add in the consent scopes, the token does not change

Comment: How do you declare API permissions in Azure AD?

Comment: Are you still looking for help with this question?